# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long , when retrieve data from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have decimal number in my Firebase Real Time Database, but when I retrieve into long value. It's going an Error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Long

Then, I tried to change the code into double. But its going Error like :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Double

But when I change the value from the Firebase to interger ex: 70, its doing well and showing value 70.0 with long.

This is my database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJSoB.png)

Java class

```
 nilaiRef.child(keys).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                listNilai.clear();
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    for(DataSnapshot dataHasil : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        final long nilai_temp = (long) dataHasil.child(users.getUid()).getValue(); 
======ERROR HERE=====
                        nilaiInfoRef.child(keys).child(dataHasil.getKey()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                    NilaiMatakuliah nilai = dataSnapshot.getValue(NilaiMatakuliah.class);
                                    nilai.setNilai(nilai_temp);

                                    listNilai.add(nilai);
                                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    Log.e("nilais","1 "+nilai.getNilai());
                                    Log.e("nilais","2 "+nilai.getNama());
                                    Log.e("nilais","3 "+nilai.getSkala());
                                    Log.e("nilais","4 "+nilai.getBobot());


                                }else{

                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                    }
                }else{

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: You store `double` value. To get `long` value from `double`, use for example `Math.round()`

Comment: How is `nilaiRef` declared?

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara but when i change to double it cast 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Comment: Don't use typecast.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the built in methods of java.lang.Long?

```
public double doubleValue()
```

Then instantiate a new java.lang.Double if you want to retain it as an object?

```
Double myDouble = new Double (nilaiRef.doubleValue()) ;
```

Conversion is done for you in [doubleValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#doubleValue--).

Comment: I dont understand , can u implement my code please.

Comment: @yehezkielyehezkiel I need to ask, are you starting out in Java?

Comment: Use `Double.valueOf(nilaiRef.doubleValue())`  t̶o̶ ̶k̶e̶e̶p̶ ̶I̶D̶E̶ ̶f̶r̶o̶m̶ ̶n̶a̶g̶g̶i̶n̶g̶ for efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your database, you have two types of data `Long` and `double`, first thing I will recommend is, while you push data to database you should convert all the values to double i.e push them with `.0` if they are `long`.

If this isn't possible you can always cast, assuming your values are going to be in range of double you can do this:

```
final double nilai_temp = (double) dataHasil.child(users.getUid()).getValue();
```

Note: `double` with small `d`, you can't cast this way using `Double`(with capital `D`).